# Edge extension from local file system

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge

I created an Edge extension what if I install manually works perfectly. But if I want to install by registry settings it doesn't work. I tried to set up the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions
key aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc
path: C:/extensions/extension.crx
version: 1.0

OR

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionForceInstalllist
key 1
value aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc;C:/extensions/extension.crx

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The group policy you mentioned is indeed for installing extensions silently, but it has some limitations. For example this paragraph in the documentation description:
[image]

In this case, I think you need to check if your current environment matches this situation. In addition, if you need to publish your extension to the Edge Add-ons webstore, you can refer to this document: [Publish a Microsoft Edge extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My extension just block the request than makes a redirection. When I install it manualy it works perfectly however Chrome coplains abot manifest v2. I'm starting to think it's because of the version of the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved to place the crx file and update.xml a file server what is reachable from everywhere. The firewall caused the problem.